# Replace uploaded image using Cloudinary and Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, cloudinary

I upload my images like this:

```
CloudinaryResponse response = await this.url.uploadImage(filePath,
        filename: "background",
        folder: "alquileres/$userId/$portfolioId/$investmentId");
```

The image names are "background_longID". I'd like to overwrite all the images.

I've found an old issue in Github but doesn't provide too much info (https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_ios/issues/87)

Answer (score 0):

You can find details about the upload and various flags for upload on the documentation page at https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_method.

If the primary concern is that you don't want Cloudinary to add the `_longId` parameter to the file name, you can set the flag `unique_filename=false` during the upload.

Another flag that you should consider is `overwrite`. By default, this flag is set to `false`. So when you re-upload, the old image is not replaced. You could set the flag `overwrite=true` as well to ensure that the new image is uploaded correctly.

Comment: the library method doesn't allow any other parameter like those:
```
Future<CloudinaryResponse> uploadImage(String imagePath,
      {String filename, String folder}) async {
    return _client.uploadImage(imagePath,
        imageFilename: filename, folder: folder);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary doesn't support integration with flutter. there are some third parties that you can use for example here: https://gist.github.com/Wizpna/eab058e15cc1533bdb73bf764078f642

If you would like to upload images to Cloudinary, our best practice is to add an upload widget. You can read more about it here:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget

Comment: I'm already using `cloudinary_client`. What's the difference from that .dart file?

Comment: And that upload widget is not what I've got right now? Or you mean something else?

Comment: an upload widget is a UI tool that you can add to your app with a few lines of code. It can let you upload images to Cloudinary.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I get what you mean. I already have a widget to upload pictures to my Cloudinary account

Answer (score 0):

For someone who might be having the same issue, here is what i did

```
     CloudinaryClient client = new CloudinaryClient(<API_KEY>, <API SECRET>, <CLOUD NAME>);
     await client.uploadImage( file.path, filename: <NAME_FOR_PHOTO>, folder: <FOLDER_NAME(OPTIONAL)>)
      .then((result){
          print("CLOUDINARY:: ${result.secure_url}==> result");
      })
      .catchError((error) => print("ERROR_CLOUDINARY::  $error"));
```

Comment: This is bad. You shouldn't place your API_KEY AND API_SECRET on flutter, as your app can be easily decompiled and the keys extracted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/cloudinary_public which does not require your API_KEY or API_SECRET